# easy_thumbnails and s3boto performances

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Django easy-thumbnails 1.1 with THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'.

I have an API that returns a json list of pictures resized to fit an iPhone screen.

The code is:

```
for p in pl:
    photos.append({
        'id': p.id,
        'url': request.build_absolute_uri(
            get_thumbnailer(p.photo)['iPhoneCombo'].url
        ) if p.photo else None,
    })
```

I have noticed that the time consumed by the get_thumbnailer is 4 time slower then using a local storage.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is there any best practice to optimize performances?

Thank you.